# Select query to same table with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb

I have a table where is multiple times same origin_id and that origin_id has always some action_name. There are 37 different action_names and most of those have some common factor like "incoming" or "einvoice" and so on. Also the table has origin_time value so I want to restrict my query to certain time frame.

At this moment my query is grouping all the origin_id's and action_name's together so there is same origin_id multiple times with unique action_name.

I have tried using EXISTS and other variations but I just don't get it working.
Can I even do this with EXISTS and NOT EXISTS?

To clear things, I have this query:

```
select  companies.origin_id, actions.action_name
    from  actions
    left join  companies on companies.id = actions.company_id
    where  actions.origin_time between '2016-07-27 00:00:00.0' AND '2016-07-28 23:59:59.0'
      and  companies.active ="1"
      and  (action_name LIKE "INTERNAL"
        or  action_name LIKE "EINVOICE%"
        or  action_name LIKE "INCOMING%"
           )
    group by  companies.origin_id, actions.action_name
    order by  actions.action_name;
```

It gives me this result:

```
origin_id                               action_name
018a9b67-cfb3-4359-b538-d9be30eaea31    EINVOICE
018a9b67-cfb3-4359-b538-d9be30eaea31    INCOMING_BANK
018a9b67-cfb3-4359-b538-d9be30eaea31    INCOMING_EINVOICE
0070d38e-467e-4fef-920a-41facd385503    EINVOICE
0070d38e-467e-4fef-920a-41facd385503    EINVOICE_BANK
0070d38e-467e-4fef-920a-41facd385503    INCOMING_EINVOICE
0191c907-921a-4548-b6ad-ae6915b938af    EINVOICE
0191c907-921a-4548-b6ad-ae6915b938af    INCOMING_BANK
0191c907-921a-4548-b6ad-ae6915b938af    INCOMING_EINVOICE
0191c907-921a-4548-b6ad-ae6915b938af    INCOMING_EINVOICE_INTERNAL
0191c907-921a-4548-b6ad-ae6915b938af    INTERNAL
01a2115b-0d21-49f1-a0f3-7c9ddd3da50d    EINVOICE
01a2115b-0d21-49f1-a0f3-7c9ddd3da50d    INCOMING_EINVOICE
01a2115b-0d21-49f1-a0f3-7c9ddd3da50d    INCOMING_EINVOICE_INTERNAL
01a2115b-0d21-49f1-a0f3-7c9ddd3da50d    INTERNAL
....
```

**My problem is that I need query which gives me origin_id's which have action_name INTERNAL and EINVOICE (and all variations of it), but if the origin_id also has action_name INCOMING (and all variations of it) I don't want that origin_id at all, even if it has those two other action_names.**

What I have tried is:

```
and
(action_name LIKE "INTERNAL%"
or action_name LIKE "EINVOICE%")
and action_name NOT LIKE "INCOMING%"
```

It works kind of. It gives me all the origin_id's which have INTERNAL and EINVOICE action_names and strips INCOMING out, but still the origin_id can have that action_name if I double check the result.

Comment: Subquery to first eliminate the 'not like this' options?

Comment: I would agree with @user3741598, create a subquery that eliminates the "not like" this data. Then, query that data to determine the data you actually need. Depending on the size of each data set it may be more efficient to switch the order of the queries as well (which I don't believe should change the overall result).

Comment: You've said a lot, but I can't understand what you actually want. Your query is way too complicated to communicate the problem; you don't need those joined tables etc. Simplify the query to the minimum that demonstrates the issue. Please provide some sample data and expected output, so we know what you want.

Comment: @Bohemian Is it any clearer now?

Comment: If 'INTERNAL' is always at the end then you need LIKE '%INTERNAL' not what you have which assumes it's at the start of the field. Also, please see my SUBQUERY comment - eliminating those which don't pass a test, then process the rest.

Comment: @user3741598 action_name's start with EINVOICE and actually there is only one INTERNAL action. Yep, I left the subquery running and left. So it will give me all other actions but not those INCOMING ones. But still there is that option, that the same origin_id has some EINVOICE action and it will show on the result.

So should I query for those three and then make some query which would eliminate all the origin_id's which have that INCOMING. So there would be left only ones which don't have that action_name at all in given time frame?

Comment: @Taapsa no, it isn't clear at all. I think it best that you show which rows of your sample data you want returned. btw, the good news is I'm pretty sure I know where the problem lies and I know how to fix it, but I don't understand which originIds you want and don't want. Maybe just a list of which are "in" and which are "out" would be helpful

Comment: @Bohemian how about now, do you get the idea?

Comment: @user3741598 that subquery doesn't help, takes too long. the database is so big.

Comment: List the items you want to match; we can give you the code.

Comment: @RickJames I have listed them. All the origin_id's with action_name INTERNAL and EINVOICE%, but if the same origin_id has INCOMING%, I don't want it.

Comment: Remove `LEFT` (unless you can justify it).  Use 3 clauses like `OR ( SELECT ... LIKE 'EINVOICE%' )` in the `WHERE`.

Comment: @RickJames I don't think that works because "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: You can `JOIN` to a subquery with multiple rows.  You can't do `IN ( SELECT..)` if that produces multiple rows.  I'm talking about `JOIN`.